# Python: Parsing Timestamps Embedded in Filenames

Tags: python, regex, django

I am working on a django project with avatar support and the system (which isn't the greatest but needs to be maintained) requires that we embed a timestamp of the form YYYYMMDDHHMM in the user generated avatar files and concats that with the user_id, for example:

23_201308080930.png

I have written a function that parses these filenames and returns the most recent timestamp:

```
def _get_timestamp(self):
    """Return the timestamp of a user's most recently uploaded avatar."""
    path = settings.USER_AVATAR_DIRECTORY + self._get_dir()
    user_id = self.user_id
    file_re = re.escape(str(user_id)) + r"_\d{12}.png"
    times = []
    [times.append(file) for file in os.listdir(path) if re.match(file_re, file)]
    if times:
        digits = [re.findall("\d{12}", timestamp) for timestamp in times]
        timestamp = sorted(digits, reverse=True)[0][0]
        return timestamp
```

It works OK, but the double [0][0] pop necessary to traverse the list within a list that is returned by the sequential regexen is a bit distasteful and overall it all seems a bit blunt. Furthermore, although the avatars are in reality spread over many directories (automatically generated by the user_id but that's not really important here) I feel that possibly the brute force regular expression searching could make a performance hit if a directory was very large.

I am interested to know what might be the optimal and idiomatic solution for this problem? Is it a candidate for generators or some form of lazy evaluation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use regexps for this; it's best to avoid them when you don't really need them. Here's how I'd do it (untested):

```
def _get_timestamp(self):
    """Return the timestamp of a user's most recently uploaded avatar."""
    path = settings.USER_AVATAR_DIRECTORY + self._get_dir()
    filenames = [filename for filename in os.listdir(path)
                 if filename.partition('_')[0] == str(self.user_id)]
    filenames.sort(reverse=True)
    return (filenames[0].rpartition('_')[2].partition('.')[0]
            if filenames else None)
```